# How to send the final reading of a stopwatch to spreadsheet using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am trying to make a web app to track the working hours. The agent will need to click a button when he is starting his work and click again the button when he is done. So I code a stopwatch. But I couldn't find a way to capture the final reading of the stopwatch and send it to the spreadsheet. Could anyone help me?

```
<script> 

    var sw = {
  /* [INIT] */
  /* sw: stopwatch */
  etime : null, // holds HTML time display
  erst : null, // holds HTML reset button
  ego : null, // holds HTML start/stop button
  timer : null, // timer object
  now : 0, // current timer
  //send : null, 

 init : function () {
    // Get HTML elements
    sw.etime = document.getElementById("sw-time");
    sw.erst = document.getElementById("sw-rst");
    sw.ego = document.getElementById("sw-go");

    // Attach listeners
    sw.erst.addEventListener("click", sw.reset);
    sw.erst.disabled = false;
    sw.ego.addEventListener("click", sw.start);
    sw.ego.disabled = false;
  },

  /* [ACTIONS] */
  tick : function () {
  // tick() : update display if stopwatch running

    // Calculate hours, mins, seconds
    sw.now++;
    var remain = sw.now;
    var hours = Math.floor(remain / 3600);
    remain -= hours * 3600;
    var mins = Math.floor(remain / 60);
    remain -= mins * 60;
    var secs = remain;

    // Update the display timer
    if (hours<10) { hours = "0" + hours; }
    if (mins<10) { mins = "0" + mins; }
    if (secs<10) { secs = "0" + secs; }
    sw.etime.innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
  },

  start : function () {
  // start() : start the stopwatch 
  // change "start" to "check in"

    sw.timer = setInterval(sw.tick, 1000);
    sw.ego.value = "Check Out"; 
    sw.ego.removeEventListener("click", sw.start);
    sw.ego.addEventListener("click", sw.stop);
  },

  stop  : function () {
  // stop() : stop the stopwatch
  //change to check out button
  //send the last reading to the spreadsheet??

    clearInterval(sw.timer);
    sw.timer = null;
    sw.ego.value = "Check In"; 
    sw.ego.removeEventListener("click", sw.stop);
    sw.ego.addEventListener("click", sw.start);

  },

  reset : function () {
  // reset() : reset the stopwatch

    // Stop if running
    if (sw.timer != null) { sw.stop(); }

    // Reset time
    sw.now = -1;
    sw.tick();
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", sw.init);

    </script>
```

Comment: Use [tag:google-sheets-api]

Comment: Are you using Google Apps Script to create your web app?

Comment: yes, I'm using Google Apps Script

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this in the html page of a webapp.  Then you could send it to a server side function with:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(msg){
  window.alert(msg);
}).saveTime(sw.now);
```

and the saveTime() function would be some thing like this.

```
function saveTime(count) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange("A1").setValue(count/60);//for minutes
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return "Thanks I got it";
}
```

Comment: I've tried it. But the stopwatch doesn't work with the server side function. Where should I amend the code?  
https://script.google.com/d/1imq7_nzoQRDV4DxWftBhjBft9u9-q4Z_OB0-JfIhOOorva98CeIW-Sx2/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I added a SpreadsheetApp.flush.  It might work now.  Writing to the spreadsheets isn't particularly fast so this may not work.